# How to extract n line after matching string and pick out second column at the same time using awk/bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that says:

```
Prediction of step:
Time = 45 s

.

.

.

.

6.45 3.99 7.40 9.22 #this is the 10th line after 'Prediction of step'

.

.

.
```

I wish to extract the line that says 'Prediction of step:' and the line afterwards, AND the second column of the 10th line, meaning 3.99:
so my output is:

```
Prediction of step:

Time = 45 s

3.99
```

so far I have managed to pull out all three lines:

```
awk '/Prediction of step:/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]; nr[NR+10]}; NR in nr' file > new_data
```

But is it possible to pull out the first two lines and only the second column of the 10th line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This uses very similar logic but, in the case of the tenth line after `Prediction of step:`, it prints only the second column:

```
$ awk '/Prediction of step:/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]; nr2[NR+10]}; NR in nr; NR in nr2{print $2}' file
Prediction of step:
Time = 45 s
3.99
```

#### How it works

- `/Prediction of step:/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]; nr2[NR+10]}`

  This creates arrays `nr` and `nr2`.
- `NR in nr`

  For lines in `nr`, we print the whole line.
- `NR in nr2{print $2}`

  For lines in `nr2`, we print only the second column.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

for the input file

```
 $ cat -n file
 1  Prediction of step:
 2  Time = 45 s
 3  .
 4  .
 5  .
 6  .
 7  .
 8  .
 9  .
10  6.45 3.99 7.40 9.22



$ awk '/Prediction of step:/{c=2;n=10} 
       c&&c--;  
       n&&!--n{print $2}' file

Prediction of step:
Time = 45 s
3.99
```

print two lines after the match and 10th line's 2nd field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/Prediction of step:/{c=1} c{ if (c++<3){print} else if (c==11){print $2; c=0} }' file
Prediction of step:
Time = 45 s
3.99
```

Comment: Can you add some additional explanation of how the code answers the question?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake sure, what part of it is unclear? It all looks extremely obvious to me but I may be biased :-).

Comment: It popped in the review queue, seeing it here, I might recommend something along the lines of @John1024's explanation?  But it has been too long since I've wrestled with awk...

Comment: I disagree. The automated flagging tool is deeply flawed in that if flags tiny, obvious scripts that have no explanation because they need none (and researching on their own would be far more beneficial than being spoon-fed to anyone who doesn't understand them) while not flagging long complex scripts because it deems the answer "long enough". There is absolutely nothing in my answer that isn't glaringly obvious when you understand awk fundamentals and it's not appropriate to explain awk fundamentals in every awk answer to every question.

Comment: That's why the tool just flags the answer as "maybe" needing additional explanation and leaves it up to humans to then comment on the answer **if appropriate**. If the review tool flags an answer related to tool X and you're not intimately familiar with tool X then just move along as you cant tell if the answer really needs additional explanation any more than the tool could.